# ctypyes.CDLL('abc.so') gives OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, c++, dll, shared-libraries, .so

I have a `.so` file (shared object library) which I want to load in Python. For this I used the following code:

```
import ctypes

libOP = ctypes.CDLL('abc.so')
```

But, it returns the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

There are two problems for me:

1. I want open this .so file and see the code inside. How can I do that? I used `readelf -a abc.so` but it didn't worked. I also tried to access it with Cygwin but failed again.
2. How can I make my python code to read this/access this .so file ?

Thanks.

Comment: .so is a *nix based library, and your error indicates you are trying to open/use it on a windows platform, this does not work... moreover it looks like you are trying to open it with a DLL constructor which can only work with windows DLL's. as for "seeing the code" the best you could achieve is seeing the functions that are exposed for use, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. This is the worst case scenario but what I really want is to see what exactly is going on in the code as well. So I want to view the code as well. Also how can I run it on windows OS ?

Comment: you cannot disassemble compiled code back into readable code. even more so if you do not know what language it was written in. it may be possible to run python within cygwin and use ctypes to load it from there, but having never tried i don't know if that would actually work.

Comment: [Windows error 193 (ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) appears when an image is treated as an executable but it is not. Although _.so_ is an _Ux_ specific file extension, since _Cygwin_ is involved, it might not be the case. Try running `hexdump -C -n 4` on your _.so_ file (_hexdump_ is an utility that can be found in your _Cygwin_ bin folder) to see what we're dealing with.